# Any way to access specific rows of text within an HTML textarea using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to both JavaScript and HTML, so I was just wondering if there was a way to access the text stored within specific rows of a text area. Here is my sample textarea:

```
<body>
   <textarea id = 'typeHere' rows = "5" cols = "60"></textarea>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the text and split it into lines:

```
 var text = document.getElementById("typeHere").value;
 var lines = text.split("\n");
```

The variable **lines** is an array of strings.

Comment: I tried something like this to test it out, but for some reason the console.log prints "test undefined"

          ```var text = document.getElementById("typeHere").value;
var lines = text.split("\n");
console.log("test", lines[1]);
```
(Sorry for the weird formatting, I don't really know how to use this)

Comment: Actually I think I got it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Get value of textarea, split on lines by `\n` and then take row. for example:

```
document.querySelector("#wmd-input").value.split('\n')[0]
```

[image: "example"]